# Типизация коллекции объектом Type

Tags: c#, generics, типы

Есть несколько коллекций:

```
private ObservableCollection<CivilRoom> _rooms = new ObservableCollection<CivilRoom>();
private ObservableCollection<CivilDoor> _doors = new ObservableCollection<CivilDoor>();
private ObservableCollection<WindowCivil> _windows = new ObservableCollection<WindowCivil>();
private ObservableCollection<CivilRamp> _ramps = new ObservableCollection<CivilRamp>();
```

Доступ к которым предоставляется через соответствующие свойства:

```
public ICollection<CivilRoom> Rooms => _rooms;
public ICollection<CivilDoor> Doors => _doors;
public ICollection<WindowCivil> Windows => _windows;
public ICollection<CivilRamp> Ramps => _ramps;
```

Для всех элементов в данных коллекциях в базовом классе определено событие:

```
public event EventHandler Deleting;
```

И метод который инициирует данное событие:

```
public void Delete()
    {
        Deleting?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

При добавлении элемента в любую из этих коллекций идет подписка на событие удаления этого элемента:

```
topologyItem.Deleting += OnElementDeleting;
```

В коде обработчика, который ниже, необходимо определить к какой коллекции относится элемент инициировавший событие, и удалить его из неё. Подумал сделать это через рефлексию, но встала проблема приведения коллекции найденной с помощью рефлексии и самого источника события к необходимому типу.

```
private void OnElementDeleting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sender));
        }

        var targetCollection = GetType().GetProperties()
            .First(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
                        p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] == sender.GetType())
            .GetValue(this);
    }
```

Comment: Вам надо привести коллекцию к тому типу чтобы что? Вернуть её из функции? Вызвать метод, который её принимает? что делать то хотите с результатом?

Comment: Вызвать на ней метод Remove(sender), и так же необходимо привести sender к этому типу.

Comment: привести Sender к типу чтобы что? Передать его куда то в другой метод?

Comment: Коллекция ваша какого типа? Зачем вы её через рефлексию ищите?

Comment: В классе есть 12 коллекций вроде этих:
public ICollection<CivilRecorder> Recorders,
public ICollection<CivilMan> People

Необходимую ищу через рефлексию, и хочу удалить из неё элемент, который sender

Comment: как вы вызывете этот метод, код которого показывали? Вы его можете сделать обобщенным? Вообще, покажите что вы делаете и для чего (код ваш с коллекциями, вши методом, как вы его вызываете), кажется мне у вас XY проблема

Comment: Есть 12 - коллекций 'private ObservableCollection<CivilRecorder> _recorders = new ObservableCollection<CivilRecorder>();', доступ к каждой из них предоставляется соответствующим свойством вроде 'ICollection<CivilRecorder> Recorders', для всех элементов в этих коллекциях в базовом классе определен  'public event EventHandler Deleting'  и 'public void Delete()
        {
            Deleting?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }'
При добавлении элемента в коллекцию производится подписка на данное событие 'topologyItem.Deleting += OnElementDeleting;'.

Comment: Вам самому комфортно читать код в своем комментарии? Я его не буду читать, добавьте всё, что я запросил, пожалуйста, в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня не так много времени и я уверен, что вы можете решить вашу задачу гораздо эффективней, чем с рефлексией (например, изменив тип события тут `public event EventHandler Deleting;` на нужный вам). Потому я вас просто предупрежу, что рефлексия - медленное зло, что ответ мой не будет блистать, но будет как то рабоать.

Итак, есть 2 класса

```
class One { }
class Two { }
```

Есть класс с полями. В нем я добавлю 2 добавлю 2 доп метода. Один для генерик вызова, другой - для вызова через object.

```
class Test
{
    public ICollection<One> One { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<One>();
    public ICollection<Two> Two { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Two>();

    public void Add(object item)
    {
        // find and call generic method
        var m = this.GetType().GetMethods()
                   .Where(x => x.Name == "Add" && x.IsGenericMethod).Single();
        var call = m.MakeGenericMethod(item.GetType());
        call.Invoke(this, new[] { item });  
    }

    // find property-collection with reflection
    public void Add<T>(T item)
    {
        foreach (var p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
            if (p.PropertyType == typeof(ICollection<T>))
                (p.GetValue(this) as ICollection<T>).Add(item);
    }   
}
```

Как использовать:

```
var t = new Test();
t.Add(new One()); // генерик
t.Add((object)new Two()); // object
```

Надеюсь, этого вам достаточно доя решения вашей задачи